# How to get from Testflight build with higher build number to App store build?

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight, ipod

I have version 1.5.2 of my app up on testflight and version 1.5.1 in the app store. I was added as an external tester in testflight, and downloaded the 1.5.2 build through testflight.

I'm trying to download the 1.5.1 version of the app from the app store but whenever I go to the app store, it just shows an open button and pressing it takes me to the testflight version 1.5.2 - I feel like there's no way for my to get back to the app store version 1.5.1

So just to go through the steps i'm doing:

- I had the app store version 1.5.1 on my phone
- I upgraded to version 1.5.2 through testflight
- I'm now unable to get version 1.5.1 from the app store

I ran this sequence with an iphone6 running iOS 9.3.5 and I was able to get version 1.5.1 from the app store without issue. I'm trying to do the same thing now with an iPod running iOS 10.2 and am not having any luck getting 1.5.1 from the app store.

Has anybody run into this issue before? Anybody know how I can get the app store version 1.5.1 back on my device?

Comment: can't you just delete the 1.5.2 version from your device and then download from the store

Comment: When I go into the app store it only shows an option to Open, rather than install the 1.5.1 version - so it appears that the 1.5.2 version has overtaken the app store version on my device.

Comment: Even when you delete the app?